# SSL certificate in Azure Key Vault differs from Application routing-add on deployed secret

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssl, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I have been trying all day to get TLS to properly work on my Ingress resources in Azure Kubernetes Service using the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl).

I noticed that when I use `kubectl get secret <secretname> -o jsonpath='{.data}'` and then base64 decode the returned "tls.crt" it returns 2 different TLS certificates of which the first one is the one showing in my browser and the second one is not showing at all. Both of the certificates are incorrect/outdated compared to what I have stored in my Key Vault.

I am not sure how to tackle this problem. I tried looking it up on our friendly neighborhood AI search engine to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TLS certificate that's showing up in your browser is incorrect or outdated, and you're seeing two different certificates when you examine the Kubernetes secret, this suggests there might be an issue with how the Ingress controller is retrieving and updating the certificates from Azure Key Vault, or with how the secret is being updated in Kubernetes.

Kindly follow below steps to resolve this issue:

connect to your aks cluster

```
az aks get-credentials -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <ClusterName>
```

make sure to enable [application routing add-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing?tabs=default,deploy-app-default#:%7E:text=Enable%20on%20an%20existing%20cluster)
[image]
Create an Azure Key Vault to store the certificate.

```
az keyvault create -g <ResourceGroupName> -l <Location> -n <KeyVaultName> --enable-rbac-authorization true
```

[image]

Create a self-signed SSL certificate to use with the Ingress using the `openssl req` command. Make sure you replace *`<Hostname>`* with the DNS name you're using as highlighted below-
[image]

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out aks-ingress-tls.crt -keyout aks-ingress-tls.key -subj "/CN=<Hostname>" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:<Hostname>"
```

Export the SSL certificate and skip the password prompt using the `openssl pkcs12 -export` command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aks-ingress-tls.crt -inkey aks-ingress-tls.key -out aks-ingress-tls.pfx
```

Import the SSL certificate into Azure Key Vault using the [`az keyvault certificate import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate#az-keyvault-certificate-import) command. If your certificate is password protected, you can pass the password through the `--password` flag. I did not give any password so I omitted the password section

```
az keyvault certificate import --vault-name <KeyVaultName> -n <KeyVaultCertificateName> -f aks-ingress-tls.pfx [--password <certificate password if specified>]
```

[image]

Retrieve the Azure Key Vault resource ID using

```
KEYVAULTID=$(az keyvault show --name <KeyVaultName> --query "id" --output tsv)
```

Then update the app routing add-on to enable the Azure Key Vault secret store CSI driver and apply the role assignment.

```
az aks approuting update -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <ClusterName> --enable-kv --attach-kv ${KEYVAULTID}
```

[image]

Create an Azure DNS zone using the [`az network dns zone create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/zone#az-network-dns-zone-create) command.

```
az network dns zone create -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <ZoneName>
```

[image]

Retrieve the resource ID for the DNS zone using the [`az network dns zone show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/zone#az-network-dns-zone-show) command and set the output to a variable named *ZONEID*.

```
ZONEID=$(az network dns zone show -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <ZoneName> --query "id" --output tsv)
```

Update the add-on to enable the integration with Azure DNS using the [`az aks approuting zone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/approuting/zone) command. You can pass a comma-separated list of DNS zone resource IDs.

```
az aks approuting zone add -g <ResourceGroupName> -n <ClusterName> --ids=${ZONEID} --attach-zones
```

[image]

Finally create the Ingress that uses a host name and a certificate from Azure Key Vault

Get the certificate URI to use in the Ingress from Azure Key Vault using the [`az keyvault certificate show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate#az-keyvault-certificate-show) command.

```
az keyvault certificate show --vault-name <KeyVaultName> -n <KeyVaultCertificateName> --query "id" --output tsv
```

The following example output shows the certificate URI returned from the command:
[image]
https://KeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/certificates/KeyVaultCertificateName/ea62e42260f04f17a9309d6b87aceb44
remeber when updating this url inside your yaml , remove the version part, only keep till-  https://KeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/certificates/KeyVaultCertificateName

Update the details from the above steps in this yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: "https://arkokeyvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/aks-ingress-tls-crt"
  name: aks-helloworld
  namespace: hello-web-app-routing
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
  - host: "9eb513efa95c4485b370.eastus.aksapp.io"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "9eb513efa95c4485b370.eastus.aksapp.io"
    secretName: "keyvault-aks-helloworld"
```

apply the same

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml -n hello-web-app-routing
```

You can verify the same.
[image]

```
kubectl get ingress -n hello-web-app-routing
```

[image]

Reference Document:

[MS Doc- Set up advanced Ingress configurations with the application routing add-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl)

[MS Doc- Get DNS zone name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl)

[MS Doc- Deploy a sample app using the certificate from the keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing?tabs=default,deploy-app-default)

Comment: Awesome instructions! Managed to fix it beforehand by just waiting another hour or so and then it picked up the correct certificate. I'll mark your answer as the solution as these should be the steps to follow to solve the issue.